# Node.Js not loading contents of json nor parsing it as JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code, when I attempt to load the contents of a json file and then log the `Name` attribute of each of the objects within the json object, I'm receiving nothing being logged

Here's my code, all help is appreciated, thank you.

```
var options = {
    host: 'www.roblox.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/catalog/json?resultsperpage=42',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunk = JSON.parse(chunk);
        for (var x in chunk) {
            console.log(chunk[x]['Name']);
        }
        //console.log(chunk);
    });
}).end();
```

Comment: what's the output of your commented out `console.log(chunk)` ?

Comment: you can't JSON.parse a chunk of JSON

Comment: absolutely nothing @azium

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I convert it to JSON?

Comment: you wait until you have the whole lot (I'm assuming a chunk isn't the whole resource, and it comes down in pieces)

Comment: what do you mean 'nothing'? Either it's `undefined` or it's not firing at all, which are very separate problems.

Comment: before I added the content-type and the JSON parsing, the full contents were being logged by the commented out line (and it was a string of a json file)

Comment: @azium i don't believe it's firing at all, not sure why. just started with node js about 30 minutes ago

Comment: that snippet wont ever do anything because of a missin `,` and `content-type` line is not valid

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for pointing that out, I removed both and used the code posted by MaximillianLaumeister and I'm still getting nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a request in Node.js, there is no guarantee that all of the data will come in a single chunk, so you need to build up your result out of the request chunks until you are sure you have all of them (i.e. the `end` event). Try the following code instead:

```
var options = {
    host: 'www.roblox.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/catalog/json?resultsperpage=42',
    method: 'GET'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    var result = "";

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        result += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        for (var x in result) {
            console.log(result[x]['Name']);
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
}).end();
```

For more information on how to make HTTP requests in Node.js, please see [this article](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request).

Comment: I'm getting ReferenceError: res is not defined when I run that

Comment: Ah, the error was due to the \ unneeded in there I believe, I removed it and I'm getting nothing logged again for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Full working version

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    host: 'www.roblox.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/catalog/json?resultsperpage=42',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { // note how you add headers
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var result = ""; // result will be built up into this

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        result += chunk; // add the chunk to the result
    }).on('end', function() { // now parse it and do things
        var json = JSON.parse(result);
        for (var x in json) {
            console.log(json[x]['Name']);
        }
        //console.log(chunk);
    });
}).end();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your JSON parse didn't work is because you called it too early during the 'data' event.  It was only sending the chunks of response at that point, and you didn't have the full response (which is text that should be valid JSON).  Do your work on the 'end' event.

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    'host': 'www.roblox.com',
    'port': 80,
    'path': '/catalog/json?resultsperpage=42',
    'method': 'GET',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
    var response_string = "";
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        response_string += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {     
        var chunk = JSON.parse(response_string);
        for (var x in chunk) {
            console.log(chunk[x]['Name']);
        }
        console.log(chunk);

    });

}).end();
```